# Flot jQuery start xaxis tick on day 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I need help about the xaxis ticks label.
I have a set of data for 1 month and will need to display a graph with 3 days interval. I used this setting

```
tickSize: [3, "day"],
```

The problem is, the first tick label starts on the 3rd day of the month. I need it to start at day 1.

Below is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cewmuv17/) from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547270/flot-rotateticks-xaxis-date-displaying-an-extra-day). (Thanks to Raidri!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set it like this:

`tickSize: [1.9, "day"]`

Now the ticksize interval is:

Jun 1, 3, 5, 7, etc...

Hope this helps someone!